# Angularjs UI-Router, no state change on hash change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

We have an accordion on the page which sets hashes for the topics, to allow deep linking. The page runs on UI-Router in HTML5Mode. When clicking on the topics, Ui-Router reloads the resolves.
How can I stop this??
I tried:
`reloadOnsearch = false` in the state definition, which works great on search params but still reloads on hash change

```
if( $transition$.$to().name == $transition$.$from().name) {
    $transition$.abort() // or return false; // or preventDefault()
}
```

Which works, but doesn't put the hash into the address, which is obviously needed.
How can I stop UI-Router from reloading the resolves and firing its state change events?

**Update with more info:**
I tried both,

```
<a ng-click="toggle();">
```

with `$location.hash("value")` 
and

```
<a href="#value">
```

with `preventDefault()` in the controller, which (as expected) didn't made a difference.

**Solution** (hopefully)
This seems to work, in case someone faces the same problem:
`$transitions.onBefore({}, function( transition ) {
    if(transition.to().name == transition.from().name) {
        const paramsCopy = Object.assign({}, transition.params());
        const stateService = transition.router.stateService;
        return stateService.target(transition.from(), paramsCopy);
    }
})`

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is you have a accordian with angular Js and the UI router reloads the page when you try to click on the accordian tabs.

Try replacing href attribute from data-target

```
<li><a data-target="#switchTabs" data-toggle="tab">Tabs</a></li>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried this as well. But I need to push the hash into the address bar to create deep linkable urls. So it's <a ng-click="toggle()"> with $location.hash(value) in the controller right now. Same problem either way: I either stop the reloading OR get an updated URL. But I need both ...